# Get PDF Printout from console application programatically in background

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get a printout of a PDF file from the printer programatically? The printout command should execute without any additional dialog popping up.

I'm using a console application and need to do this without using any 3rd party library or tool

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show people your effort first..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of what @Freelancer wrote, I use the following method as it uses Adobe's registry settings to find the path to the Acrobat reader executable, but it prints silently to the default printer:

```
private void PrintPdf(string fileName)
{
    var hkeyLocalMachine = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Software\Adobe\Acrobat");
    if (hkeyLocalMachine != null)
    {
        var exe = hkeyLocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Exe");
        if (exe != null)
        {
            var acrobatPath = exe.GetValue(null).ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acrobatPath))
            {
                var process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = acrobatPath,
                        Arguments = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "/T {0}", fileName)
                    }
                };

                process.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this solution also, I get the Acrobat reader opens and closes automatically. As pointed out in Freelancer's answer. I think it's because I'm using Acrobat Reader 8.

Comment: Tried this using Acrobat Reader 11 also. Still the windows opens and closes

Comment: A truly silent PDF print might not be possible, see this article [Print PDF Silently in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546675/print-pdf-silently-in-c-sharp).  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework provides classes in the System.Diagnostics namespace that can be used to start external processes.  I have used the following code in several projects to start various executables and we can use it to start Adobe Acrobat Reader too.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
private static void RunExecutable(string executable, string arguments) 
  {
   ProcessStartInfo starter = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, arguments);
   starter.CreateNoWindow = true;
   starter.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   starter.UseShellExecute = false;
   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo = starter;
   process.Start();
   StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
   using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) 
   {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null) 
    {
     buffer.Append(line);
     buffer.Append(Environment.NewLine);
     line = reader.ReadLine();
     Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
   }
   if (process.ExitCode != 0) 
   {
    throw new Exception(string.Format(@"""{0}"" exited with ExitCode {1}. Output: {2}", 
executable, process.ExitCode, buffer.ToString());  
   }
  }
```

**You can print your PDF by incorporating the above code into your project and using it as follows:**

```
string pathToExecutable = "c:\...\acrord32.exe";
RunExecutable(pathToExecutable, @"/t ""mytest.pdf"" ""My Windows PrinterName""");
```

**Note:** This code belongs to http://aspalliance.com/514_CodeSnip_Printing_PDF_from_NET.all

You can follow all the discussion for this code on this link.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: There is a problem i'm facing with this code. I was able to get the printout through the printer but Adobe PDF window opens and closes automatically.

Comment: Which version you are using? its perfect for Acrobat Reader 9

Comment: I'm using Acrobat Reader 8. Maybe that's the issue

Comment: Hardcoding paths is bad practice, you'll be forced to recompile to change them

Comment: Agree, i think for the hardcoded path, can go ahead with Fooksie's solution

Comment: @Alex yeah alex you are right, Nips just tried to help you as much i can.

Comment: @Freelancer tried this using Acrobat Reader 11 also. Still the window opens up and closes automatically.